# Remove all lines between 2 lines with specific patterns with a perl one-liner and regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I have a huge text (EDIT : in fact not that "huge", just larger and messier...) looking like this :

```
1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
LERUTH, 1935b, Ex. biol., XXIV, p. 240.
JEANNEL, 1909, Biosp., X, p. 484.
pp. 378 et 794.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
SCHMITZ, 1909, Ex. biol., If, p. 89. — WoLr, 
Catalogus, III, p. 379.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons
```

I want to use regular expression with a perl one-liner to tranform this text into :

```
1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons
```

So I want to remove all lines that are between a line starting with a digit then a dot then a space
and the lines starting with the words "Province" or "Limbourg"

It works perfectly when I test following regex `(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)` with the following replacement : `$1\n$3` in the following website :
https://regex101.com/ (PCRE2 flavor but it works with all flavors).

However when I try it with my perl one-liner it does nothing :

```
echo "1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
LERUTH, 1935b, Ex. biol., XXIV, p. 240.
JEANNEL, 1909, Biosp., X, p. 484.
pp. 378 et 794.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
SCHMITZ, 1909, Ex. biol., If, p. 89. — WoLr, 
Catalogus, III, p. 379.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons" | 

perl -pe 's/(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)/\1\n\3/g'
```

I guess I have to activate some mode or modifier ?
Or maybe something is wrong with the regex but then why would it work on the above mentioned website ?

Comment: `perl -ne '$s=0 if /^(Province|Limbourg)/; print if !$s; $s=1 if /^\d\. /'` or `awk '/^(Province|Limbourg)/{s=0} !s; /^[0-9]\. /{s=1}'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command

```
perl -pe 's/(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)/\1\n\3/g'
```

is running the equivalent of this

```
while (<>) {
    s/(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)/\1\n\3/g ;
    print;
}
```

The problem is your regular expression is being run against each line individually - that will always fail.

You need to read the slurp the input file into a big string and run the regular expression against that. That is achieved by adding `-0777` to the commandline.

Also, the `m` modifier is needed in your regex to make `^` match against the start of a line, rather than the start of the string. Below from https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers that explains what `m` does.

> m Treat the string being matched against as multiple lines. That is,
> change "^" and "$" from matching the start of the string's first line
> and the end of its last line to matching the start and end of each
> line within the string.

One other point. In Perl the use of `\1`, `\2` to reference the capture groups isn't idiomatic perl. The usual form is to write as `$1`, `$2`.

Running follows.

```
echo '1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
LERUTH, 1935b, Ex. biol., XXIV, p. 240.
JEANNEL, 1909, Biosp., X, p. 484.
pp. 378 et 794.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
SCHMITZ, 1909, Ex. biol., If, p. 89. — WoLr, 
Catalogus, III, p. 379.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons' | perl -0777 -pe 's/(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)/$1\n$3/gm'
```

Output is

```
1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons
```

Comment: That seems to be a good lead but it works only for the first match... The output should contain 6 lines in this case. In you answer it contains 8 lines...

Comment: It seems to work properly with 
`perl -0777 -pe 's/(^\d\. .*)\n(.*\n)*?(Province|Limbourg)/$1\n$3/gm`. So if I understand well we have to slurp the entire text with the `-0777` option and add the `m` modifier for multiline mode. Please adapt your answer so that I can accept it... And thank you for the help !

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that the "*huge*" file can still be read into memory at once, as the attempt in the question seems to be going for

```
perl -0777 -pe's/^[0-9]\. .*?\n\K.*?(Province|Limbourg)/$1/msg' file
```

Comments

- With `-0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D) the whole file is read into a string at once ("slurped"), available in [$_](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_)
- [Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers): `/m` makes anchors `^` and `$` match beginning and end of line *inside* a multiline string; `/s` makes `.` match a linefeed as well; `/g` keeps matching through the string
- After matching the line starting with the number (etc), that [\K](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK) drops all previous matches (they are not "consumed" out of the string) so we don't have to worry about putting it back
- Then `.*?` matches everything -- including newlines! (by `/s` modifier) -- up to the first `(Province|Lumbourg)`, which is captured so to be put back into the string
- This continues since `^` matches line beginnings further in the string as well

With regards to capture-and-replace, another option is to use [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

```
perl -0777 -pe's/^[0-9]\. .*?\n\K.*?(?=Province|Limbourg)//msg' file
```

Now we need not replace anything at all since the lookahead doesn't consume the characters it matches (it only "looks ahead" to assert that they are there)

Both these print the desired output with the provided input.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. The combined use of the s and m modifier made me very confused but it is perfectly clear now (even if the s modifier does not work on the testing website I use). The `\K` trick and lookahead are just beautiful !

Comment: Just for my future self : the regex with \K and lookahead but without s mode : `perl -0777 -pe 's/^\d\. .*\n\K(.*\n)*?(?=Province|Limbourg)//mg`

Comment: @GillesSanMartin  Without the `/s` mode the `.*\n` will stop at the first newline; so it can only capture _one_  line.  For the first one that's OK, because that is one line -- but the second one (after `\K`) should match multiple lines.  So we do need that `/s` in this problem :)

Comment: @GillesSanMartin "_the s modifier does not work on the testing website I use_"  -- that's strange.  This is a fairly standard feature I thought (`DOTALL` in Python)

Comment: I was talking about this website https://regex101.com/ in which you can literally test different regexes on a given text. But I realized in the meanwhile that you can indeed set the options (including "s") at the extreme right of the regex entry field (the default mode being /gm) !

Answer (score 3):

This would seem to be a good use for the "flip-flip" operator. This seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Don't print the lines between the two marker lines
  print unless /^\d+\./ .. /^(Province|Limbourg)/;

  # But actually, we want to print the two marker lines
  print if /^\d+\./ or /^(Province|Limbourg)/;
}

__DATA__
1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
LERUTH, 1935b, Ex. biol., XXIV, p. 240.
JEANNEL, 1909, Biosp., X, p. 484.
pp. 378 et 794.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
SCHMITZ, 1909, Ex. biol., If, p. 89. — WoLr,
Catalogus, III, p. 379.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons
```

The output I get is:

```
1. Ocalea picata STEPHENS.
Province de Luxembourg :
Marche-en-Famenne :Fond-des-Vaulx », Trou des \utons (B.
1. Oxypoda (Oxypoda) opaca GRAvENHoRsT.
Limbourg belge:
Sinsin-lez-Heure, près de Marche-en-Famenne : Trou des Nutons
```

It's not a one-liner, but I guess it could be turned into one pretty easily.

**Update:** I just wanted to note that this solution processes the file line by line (the other solutions all use `-0777` to read the whole file into memory). We're told the OP's file is "huge" but we aren't given any data to quantify that. If the file is truly huge, then reading it all into memory might be problematic, whereas reading it a line at a time will always work.

Comment: Thank you @DaveCross. I must however apologize as I realize that the term "huge" is clearly inappropriate in my case. The text is in fact tiny : a few thousands of lines. What I meant was that the real life example was larger and more complex than the reproducible example... Sorry for that !